# neo4j 2.1.1 sample datasets not working

Tags: neo4j

I've installed Neo4j Community v2.1.1 in a Windows 7 x64 environment, then tried to play around with sample datasets (drwho, cineast, etc.) but couldn't load any of them. Returned error is "Starting Neo4j Server failed: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase". Setting allow_store_upgrade=true in {sample dataset folder}/neo4j.properties didn't solve it out.

Comment: Thanks for the note, we'll check them and make them available for the current versions (2.0 and 2.1.1). Some of them are probably still for 1.9. But feel free to check out our other live examples on http://gist.neo4j.org

Comment: I didn't know about the live examples, many thanks Michael! I'll be looking forward to download the ones for v2.1.1

Comment: I think you can only upgrade one minor version at a time, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647332/error-moving-neo4j-database-when-upgrading-from-1-9-4-to-2-0-1