# How do I extract raw data from the neo4j examples?

Tags: neo4j

The neo4j [example data](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/example_data) does not work in the most recent version 2.1.2 of neo4j as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042383/neo4j-2-1-1-sample-datasets-not-working) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647332/error-moving-neo4j-database-when-upgrading-from-1-9-4-to-2-0-1/21649346).  They are built for 1.9 and apparently can only be upgraded to 2.0, not 2.1.  Is there a way to extract the raw data as a csv or cypher file (with a bunch of CREATE statements) from either the tarballs (which contain a graph.db, which I do not understand) or the associated github repositories (which I also do not understand)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to us to update the datasets, thanks for pointing it out, I think we'll also put them into versioned subdirectories, so it is easier to see which version they are in.

In general for small enough datasets, you can use the neo4j-shell and the "dump" command to generate cypher statements.

Also in the neo4j browser you can actually download the query results as CSV.

I also wrote a set of [helper tools](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools) for the neo4j shell that allows you to export and import data as csv, graphml and other formats.

Comment: Thank you! Will your tools work in 1.9 though? I ask because 'dump' is available in 2+ but not 1.9.