# How do I start with Example Datasets in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, dataset

Last week I installed Neo4j 2.1.2 (before I was working with Version 2.0.3). I could use my existing databases because i allowed to grade them up. But when I try to use a new example dataset from neo4j.org (I wanted to use the big movie dataset) I am not able to start the server. In console.log I see the following ERROR

```
ERROR o.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase - Startup failed: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@5872c88c' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@11e51b89' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.: 'neostore.nodestore.db' has a store version number that we cannot upgrade from. Expected 'NodeStore v0.A.1' but file is version 'NodeStore v0.A.0'.
```

After that I downloaded a dataset i am already using once again and wanted to start the server with that datasat but it does not work either. What do I have to change (maybe configuration? to enable upgrading in "neo4j.properties" file seems not to suffice) to be able to use the neo4j example datasets?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376544/how-do-i-extract-raw-data-from-the-neo4j-examples

Answer (score 0):

Reason is your data are for different (older) version of Neo4j.

If you want to migrate your data to version of Neo4j, which you have installed you need to change following settings:

**neo4j.properties**

```
# Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from an older version.
allow_store_upgrade=true
```

Answer (score -1):

Click Options --> Database Base Tuning --> Edit and then in the notepad uncomment the row "allow_store_upgrade=true" as on the screenshots:

[Database Tuning-->Edit 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JuqK.jpg)

[Database Tuning-->Edit 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ubJY.jpg), after that save and the server starts again, at least it worked fine to me.

Comment: "server starts again" - do you mean manual restart or it happens automatically?