# Prepared data set "Musicbrainz" doesn't work - Detected incorrectly shut down database, performing recovery

Tags: neo4j, musicbrainz

I struggling to get the "Musicbrainz" data set running on my local machine (MacBook Air, Mountain Lion).

What I did? (Basically what the video said)

1. Downloaded data set directly from http://www.neo4j.org/develop/example_data
2. Downloaded fresh Neo4j-Community-2.1.5
3. Extracted the data set, renamed it to graph.db and copied to /neo4j-community-2.1.5/data/graph.db
4. Run the server: `./bin/neo4j console`, but neo does not start - not even an exception is thrown!!!!

> Gerardos-MacBook-Air:neo4j-community-2.1.5 Gery$ ./bin/neo4j console
>   WARNING: Max 256 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended.
>   See the Neo4j manual. Starting Neo4j Server console-mode... Using
>   additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
>   -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled 2014-10-09 15:40:31.700+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms
>   based on -1 Detected incorrectly shut down database, performing
>   recovery..

I tried several settings in neo4j.properties, but nothing, see properties below ...

> use_memory_mapped_buffers=true
>   neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=300M
>   neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=3G
>   neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=500M
>   neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=500M
>   neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=0M
>   neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory=15M
>   neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory=15M
>
> allow_store_upgrade=true

I was hoping that this would work out of the box. What am I missing ...?

Comment: See [this page in the manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/linux-performance-guide.html#_setting_the_number_of_open_files) to fix your open files issue.  Start there and post back.

Comment: I increased the limit for the # of open files. But still the same error `Detected incorrectly shut down database, performing recovery..` Any other ideas?

Comment: Go into the `data` folder and rename `graph.db` to `graph.db.old`, then try starting again.

Comment: neo4j starts, but does not pick up the musicbrainz graph dump (that I renamed to data/graph.db.old); it creates a new, empty graph.db folder. Do you know some other where I can get some more hints? I just want to evaluate Neo4j's performance with a (very) large data set ..

Comment: Hmm... This was made for Neo4j 2.0, I wonder if anything needs to happen for it to work in 2.1? You may need to enable the option to allow a db store upgrade. Maybe try installing 2.0, getting that db working, then upgrade to 2.1.5. http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/deployment-upgrading.html has some instructions.

Comment: @GerardoNavarroSuarez sorry for bothering but... any news with that? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @GerardoNavarroSuarez please if still interested, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21649346/573034, for me it fixes the issue.

Comment: @Paolo I got it to work with Neo4j 2.0.X (older version). But I could not upgrade the store to get it work with the current Neo4j 2.1.5 ...

Comment: @GerardoNavarroSuarez with the trick described in that answer I was able to navigate the database on 127.0.0.1 in neo 2.1.6; though, looking deeper I also found that the database obtained this way is corrupted (labels are empty). Then I followed the [manual procedure](https://github.com/redapple/sql2graph/blob/master/MUSICBRAINZ_README.md) but have [another issue](https://bitbucket.org/lalinsky/mbslave/issue/8/).